# SciKit-Learn: Trouble with TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I'm trying to use TFIDF to get features from titles of text articles.  I'm doing the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus_title = result_df['_title'].tolist()
tfidf_transformer_title = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 1, ngram_range = (1,1), use_idf = True, stop_words='english')
tfidf_df_title = tfidf_transformer_title.fit_transform(corpus_title)
tfidf_df_title
```

However, I get an error at this line:

```
----> 4 tfidf_df_title = tfidf_transformer_title.fit_transform(corpus_title)
```

The error is:

```
    205 
    206         if self.lowercase:
--> 207             return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
    208         else:
    209             return strip_accents

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

I'm not sure how it's possible to get this error.  I checked the docs and it looks like `TfidfVectorizer` uses UTF-8 as its default encoding.

Any idea how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Your corpus seems to have some problematic entries.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is there a way to skip these entries?

Comment: Not familiar with pandas, but you could probably take a look at exactly what data is causing the problem, and then use boolean indexing to filter it out.

Comment: Using `result_df['_title'].dropna()` should drop what appear to be empty entries in your corpus

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
tfidf_transformer_title = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 1,lowercase = False, ngram_range = (1,1), use_idf = True, stop_words='english')
```